# remove text on hover on lightning-input

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning-input text box which is required. On hovering , it displays a default message like below image. This message is displayed only when marked as required.[image]

```
<lightning:input aura:id="accID" type="text" value="{!v.accNum}" required="true" variant="label-hidden" />
```

Is there a way to disable this message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like setting the `required` attribute is causing this behavior and there is no way to disable it. You may want to try one of the `messageWhen*` functions or the `validity` function. However this will make you lose the red asterisk. In that case you may have to build the input yourself based on the https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#site-main-content design

Comment: seems like this is the only option.But, this default message is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: I know it stinks. But hey, maybe building manually will give more granular control to do something better.